# python gtk equivalent of PIL.Image tobytes()

Tags: python

what is gtk equivalent of PIL.Image tobytes()?

```
i = PIL.Image.open('image.png')
data = i.tobytes()
```

I am trying to get screen with GTK and transform it to the same bytes as in previous PIL:

```
import gtk, PIL.Image

img_width = gtk.gdk.screen_width()
img_height = gtk.gdk.screen_height()
data = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(
  gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,
  False,
  8,
  img_width,
  img_height
)  
data.get_from_drawable(
  gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window(),
  gtk.gdk.colormap_get_system(),
  0, 0, 0, 0,
  img_width,
  img_height
)
data = data.tobytes() #<-- here trying to get bytes
```

Comment: Are you aware that you're using an outdated version of gtk? The current version is Gtk3, which you import through `from gi.repository import Gtk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`pixbuf.get_pixels()`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--get-pixels).

Note that it's possible for the returned data to contain padding:

> Rows in the image are stored top to bottom, and in each row pixels are
>   stored from left to right. There may be padding at the end of a row.
>   The "rowstride" value of a pixbuf, as returned by
>   gdk_pixbuf_get_rowstride(), indicates the number of bytes between
>   rows.

(from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/unstable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html#gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.description).)

You can use string/bytes operations to remove this padding, or alternatively use [`pixbuf.save_to_callback`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gdkpixbuf.html#method-gdkpixbuf--save-to-callback) to save the image in a raw RGB format with no padding.